# Ajax can success() handle two type of return?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Working in a C# ASP.NET project with JavaScript/Jquery/jqGrid.

New task is to have a page to i) accept an Excel input file, ii) use the column ID to look up additional information, and iii) generate a new Excel file using some columns from input file and all columns returned from database.

I have completed that, but just want to do a bit more error handling. In the stored procedure, if everything works fine, it returns a data table (or in Oracle term, a CURSOR). If there is an error, I have added a catch block and return an error message.

I modify the AJAX call. Beside **adding** dataType as 'text', I expect the return as XML.

```
$.ajax({
    // POST
    // URL: url to call that stored procedure
    dataType: text,
    success: function (response) {
        // now the response is XML (don't know why... 
        // specify dataType as 'text', but get XML...)
        // If response contains 'string' tag, report error.
    },
    failure: ...
})
```

Here is what I used to do. I don't specify the dataType but somehow that works.

```
$.ajax({
    // POST
    // ... rest is same but without the dataType
    success: function (response) {
        Download( response )
        // The file is already and placed in Download directory. 
        // Call 'Download()' will actually make the download happen
        // But here response is just a path to the Download directory +
        // download file name.
```

And Download() is:

```
function Download(url) {
    document.getElementById('my_iframe').src = <%=ResolveUrl("~/")%> +url;
    return false
};
```

How can I have the success function handle both type of response?

(Just for your information: The front-end page is ASP.NET. Button click will call a JavaScript function. The function calls a web service function via $.ajax(). As there are many rows, the web service function calls a function in a database class many times - each time pass in just one ID. The function will in return call stored procedure.)

---

Edit: Thanks for solution from Mustapha Larhrouch. Here are some points that I have to adjust:

1. Add dataType.
2. If response is XML, check if error.
3. If not XML, just download.

And here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    // POST
    // URL
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (response) {
        if (isXML(response)) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response);
            $xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var errMsg = $xml.find("string").text();

            if (errMsg != "" ) {
                // pop up a dialog box showing errMsg
            }
        } 
        else {
            Download(response);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check if the response is an xml if it's parse it, if not the response is a string. and you can use this function to check if the response is an xml :

```
function isXML(xml){
    try {
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml); //is valid XML
        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        // was not XML
        return false;
    }
}


$.ajax({
    // POST
    // ... rest is same but without the dataType
    success: function (response) {
        if(isXML(response){
            Download( response )
        }
        else{
           //report as error
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. You point me to the right direction. For those who are reading this, please see the edit part of my question. There are points I have to add.